# Rearranging a packed question

Tags: word-choice, grammar, phrase-requests

I'm having a hard time fixing this sentence. I know there's something wrong with it, but I don't know what it is nor do I know what it's called. Any help would be appreciated.

I am sending an email to my Macroeconomics teacher regarding the equation below:

---

**Imports decrease + Exports Increase = Net Exports Increase**

---

My question that needs fixing:

> Does this also mean that if exports increase and nothing happens to imports, will that lead to Net Exports increasing?

Comment: What, exactly, are you asking?  You don’t seem to be talking about an English sentence.  You have posted a mathematical formula, which is off-topic here.  Are you really asking whether an increase in exports leads to an increase in exports?

Comment: It sounds to me like you are asking about the last sentence in your post, rather than the bolded equation. Is that correct? If so, you should edit your question so that the most important piece (i.e., the sentence you are asking about) stands out more, and that it is clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

It looks fine to me.

You could also word it: 
"Does this also mean that an increase in exports will cause an increase in net exports, even if imports are constant?"

(Also I'm pretty sure the answer to that question is yes.)

```
x + y = z, therefore (x + w) + y = z + w
```

(Sorry for putting math in the English forum...)

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about the sentence

> Does this also mean that if exports increase and nothing happens to imports, will that lead to Net Exports increasing?

the simplest way to fix the sentence is to leave out the "dead wood" (unnecessary words that make the sentence more complicated):

> Does this also mean that if Exports increase and nothing happens to Imports,  Net Exports will increase?

Also, capitalizing "Imports" and "Exports" (just as you did with "Net Exports") makes it clear that you are referring to the terms in the equation.